# How to Change Pitch Bend in MIDI?

Tags: midi, ableton-live, pitch

I use Kontakt 4 to play a guitar on my keyboard on my song. So, naturally I use MIDI. I've recorded the whole song a couple of times and it's perfect except for one movement with the pitchbend knob on my piano.

Is there any way to fix this in Ableton Live now, or do I have to record all over again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you recorded your MIDI into MIDI clips (and weren't recording just the audio out from Kontakt), there certainly is!

Pitchbend messages are stored in clip envelopes, similar to other MIDI CC messages. Open your MIDI clip in clip view at the bottom, and click on the "e" in the lower left corner to bring up the Envelopes box. In the choosers there, find Pitchbend (I believe it's under MIDI Control, but I don't have it in front of me to check).

The pitchbend curve should show up in the clip editing box. Select the range where you have extra Pitchbend movement you don't want and delete it.